# Ctrl+Alt+T stopped working 15.04

Tags: 15.04

After I upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> combination stopped working.

Also the keyboard layout indicator disappeared from the tray while layout switching actually works. But the switcher is visible in lightdm for some reason.

How can I investigate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a reboot I found out that if guake is not running ctr+alt+t combination launches it.

So the problem was that x-terminal-emulator was switched to guake instead of the gnome terminal. To switch it back type:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

And select `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper`